# retrieving last message when joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm currently retrieving data from 3 different tables. One of those tables contain messages sent which relates to each ID.

What I'm currently trying to do but have been unsuccessful is retrieve the last message on record for each ID.

Help please-

```
select
   C.id ,
   C.business,
   AP.firstname,
   AP.lastname,
   M.comments,
   M.dateread 
from
   claims C 
JOIN
   affected_people AP 
      ON C.ID = AP.claimid 
join
   Messages M 
      on M.claimid = C.ID
```

Comment: Either just look around SO for the answer or, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. I've been searching several threads but have yet to find one with the right combo codes that would give the results needed. Happy Holdays

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if that works for mysql:

```
select *
from(
    select
       C.id ,
       C.business,
       AP.firstname,
       AP.lastname,
       M.comments,
       M.dateread,
       max(M.dateread) over (partition by c.id)  max_dateread
    from
       claims C 
    JOIN
       affected_people AP 
          ON C.ID = AP.claimid 
    join
       Messages M 
          on M.claimid = C.ID)
          where max_dateread=dateread
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I get a server version error #1064 on the use of this code `max(M.date) over (partition by c.id)` . I tried fiddling with it but got no where fast, well after 10-15 minutes. Anyways, Thanks and Happy Holidays..

Answer (score -1):

Just add in

```
Order by M.dateread desc
```

Comment: This would change the order of what is returned, but the question is asking to retrieve the last message, not messages in reverse chronological order.